# Using setcookie in body content

Tags: php, html, cookies, setcookie

In PHP manual for `setcookie()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) we learn that cookie is sent along with the rest of HTTP headers. This means it has to be sent before any output from the script, including html and head tags.

To my suprise below code is working fine:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Cookie test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Proin ornare sapien in justo laoreet imperdiet. Duis bibendum iaculis dui id consequat. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
    <?php
    setcookie('test_cookie', uniqid(), time()+3600);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the `setcookie()` function is called inside the body tag. I use Chrome dev tools to view current cookies and the `test_cookie` is listed.
[image]

Why does the above code doesn't trigger any error message from the PHP ?

I'm using XAMPP 3.2.2, PHP Version 7.0.9, Chrome 62.0.3202.94

Comment: are you using `output buffering`?

Comment: Does the cookie stick? Can you check if the cookie is still there later on another page?

Comment: Sorry to say but you have got confused and haven&#39;t understand the logic well.
It&#39;s right cookies are sent over HTTP whenever required. But it doesn&#39;t mean it needs to be set before page or at starting.
i can be possible that u set the cookie anywhere u wish and send it over HTTP to server only when u wish. Feel free to write if need more understanding

Comment: It is my understanding that using `setcookie` will send HTTP headers which, if done after page load, will throw an error unless `output buffering` is enabled. Though error reporting level may be set such that errors are not displayed regardless.

Comment: @RamRaider you're right. I had output_buffering option set to 4096 in php.ini file and that allowed to send cookies from the body. Once I disable this option, the above code produces error.